# Make sure a product has at least one category

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello wonderful Stackoverflowrians!

I have this [DB diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcHH6.png) and I have this postgresql to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE products (    
    prod_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    description text,
    purchase_price numeric(10,2) NOT NULL,
    selling_price numeric(10,2) NOT NULL,
    weight numeric(10,2),
    min_quantity int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE categories (
    cat_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(100),
    parent int REFERENCES categories ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE product_categories (
    prod_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES products,
    cat_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES categories,
    PRIMARY KEY (prod_id, cat_id)
);
```

As you see I have categories with multiple sub-categories, products, and table to make relations between them so I can assign multiple categories to a product. 
While writing down the create table queries interesting question pop-up in my mind.

I am not sure if it's even possible but, I am trying to find a way to assure that every product is assigned to least one category. Any ideas?

Comment: should that be handled by your application rather from the database?

Answer (score 0):

One method of ensuring that every product is in at least one category is to have a "primary" category in the product table:

```
primary_categoryid int not null references categories(cat_id)
```

This does make the primary categoryid "different" from other categories, because it is not in the `product_categories` table.

If you attempt a solution where you require a row in `product_categories`, then you have a problem.  The row in `product_categories` would need to refer to a valid product -- but a product is not valid (by your definition) until it has a category.